# AngularJs: Radio Button Not Selected By Default

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following snippet in my directive template

```
'<li ng-repeat="f in foos">' +
'<input type="radio" ng-change="foo(f.key)" ng-model="selectedFoo" name="foos" id="{{f.key}}" value="{{f.key}}">{{f.value}}</input>' +
'</li>' +
```

In my link method I have

```
scope.foos = [
                    { key: 'a', value: 'A', checked: true, symbol: 'a' },
                    { key: 'b', value: 'B', symbol: 'b' },
                    { key: 'c', value: 'C', symbol: 'c' }
                ];
scope.selectedFoo = "a";
```

I have method foo that does this

```
scope.foo = function(selectedValue) {
                    scope.selectedMatchType = selectedValue;
                };
```

There are two problems that I am facing

1. Even though I have set ng-model to selectedFoo, the first element in the dropdown is not set by default when the radio buttons get rendered.
2. The method foo is only called once for each element in the list.  So, for example if I click on A, foo is called, if I then click on B, foo is called, if I click on A again foo is not called, but if I then click on C, foo is calle.

What is wrong here?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle or equivalent?

Comment: Works fine in a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpeinar/5gj9y6k4/2

Comment: @HenrikPeinar.  In fact no it doesn't.  If you look at the console you will see that the fiddle also only calls the foo method once for each item in the list.

Comment: Please see my answer and updated fiddle. I misleadingly only checked for the default radio input selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) creates it's own scope for every template which means you'll have to use $parent in ng-model for the input.

```
ng-model="$parent.selectedFoo"
```

Also a working fiddle with your code example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpeinar/5gj9y6k4/

Comment: That is brilliant.  This fixed issue 2 for me but issue 1 is not fixed yet.  I simply cannot get the first item in the dropdown to be selected by default.  Any idea why?  I will still mark this as answer though.

Comment: This weird though because in the fiddle the default selection is working fine, even if the selectedFoo variable is changed. It checks the radio button which value is already in the "ng-model".